# Fixed subspace of an complex orthogonal representation

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V\cong\mathbb{C}^n$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space. We have essentially one degenerate symmetric bi-linear form $(-,-)$, namely the one corresponding to the identity matrix.

Let $O_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be the complex orthogonal group which is defined as the subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ consisting of $g$ with $(gx,gy)=(x,y),\forall x,y\in V$. $O_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ acts on $V\otimes V$ as $g(a\otimes b)=ga\otimes gb$.

**Problem:** Show that the fixed point subspace is one-dimensional for all $n$.

I have no idea in general, except that brutal calculation in dimension $2$ made me guess the subspace is generated by $e_1\otimes e_1+...+e_n\otimes e_n$. This is indeed the case, since $ge_i\otimes ge_i=(g_{ji}e_j)\otimes(g_{ki}e_k)=g_{ji} g_{ki} e_j \otimes e_k=\delta_{jk} e_j \otimes e_k=e_i\otimes e_i$ (Einstein summation taken).

At higher dimensions, I don't even know whether the determinant of an orthogonal matrix would be ${\pm 1}$.

Comment: $A \in O_n(\mathbb{C}) \iff A^T\cdot A = I$, so $(\det A)^2 = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks! I should have remembered that $\det A=\det A^T$ in any case.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I made some progress. If we view $w \in V\otimes V$ as a matrix, then $g(w)=w$ is equivalent to $A^TwA=W,\forall A\in O_n(\mathbb{C})$, seen by calculating componentwise. It remains to prove that the only matrices commuting with orthogonal ones are the scalars.

Comment: Yet this approach does not explain the problem well.

Comment: That should be doable by considering only $A \in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ and the real and imaginary part of $W$ separately.